# How merge the exe and msi file in single setup?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm creating a setup using visual studio setup project , it will create two files one is msi and second one is exe. but i want to Create single file using that.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out IExpress.
This is a built in tool in many versions of Windows which you can use to create a self extracting directive file.
You simply add the msi and setup.exe and choose to run the setup.exe.

This tool creates an SED file which you could run in a post build event so you do not have to do it manually after every build.

You could follow the directions in this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k976yEXX11k

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress

Comment: By generating that executable using IExpress, the Windows Defender treats that file as a virus and deletes that file. Will signing that executable solve that problem, or should I find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to uncheck **Create setup program to install prerequisite components** in the [Deployment Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1befw7hy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - but think through, carefully, the meaning of that option.

If you don't create the setup.exe, then your program can't be installed on machines which are missing some or all of your pre-requisites.

Also, be aware that setup projects are no longer supported in VS2012 - so it may be worth the time now to start investigating other setup authoring options such as WiX.

Comment: I'm confused - I'm using VS 2022 and I created a setup project.  Are we talking about different things?